# Getting rid of this tag will take [collaboration]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [collaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaboration) tag has 473 questions. It has the following tag description:

> Collaboration is combining the effort of people in real-time to get things done, either by working side-by-side or through tools such as web conferencing, instant messaging, IRC, etc.

Clearly, this has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

Predictably, this tag is also ambiguous and frequently misused. It's used for everything from Unity Collaborate to style guides to proper Github workflows.

Given that this tag is blatantly off-topic on the face of it, can we burninate it?

Comment: "*Given that this tag is blatantly off-topic on the face of it, can we burninate it?*" but if we do it through our combined effort, aren't we ultimately living up to what the tag is about? Are we hypocrites? Or is this what the tag would have always wanted?